# Generate URL in MS Access with 2 field variables

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to generate a URL based on 2 fields in an access database.

I can get it to work with one variable, but have tried a number of iterations to get the second one to work properly.

the onclick VBA that I am using is:

```
Private Sub GenerateLink_Click()
Dim Filename As String
Dim Filedir As String

Filename = "https://hiddenforsecurity.com&password_encrypted=true&patient_last_name= '   
& [patient last name]' &patient_id=' & [casenumber]'"
RetVal = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe " & Filename, 1)

End Sub
```

I can get the first part to work when I do this:

```
Filename = "https://hiddenforsecurity.com&password_encrypted=true&patient_last_name="   
& [patient last name]
```

But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get the rest of it to work. I need to append the &patient_id= [casenumber] to also be apart of the link.

thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
    Filename = "https://hiddenforsecurity.com&password_encrypted=true&patient_last_name=" & [patient last name] & "patient_id=" & [casenumber]
```

Answer (score 1):

You put everything in double quotes there.  You need to break the double quotes to stop the string while you concatenate.

```
Filename = "https://hiddenforsecurity.com&password_encrypted=true&patient_last_name=" & [patient last name] & "patient_id=" & [casenumber]
```

I'm not sure what `patient_id` is referencing though, if it is in a form you need `me.patient_id`.  You probably know that though.